# Double Entry on Select?

Tags: html, select

I have 2 select tags for a form for someone's Birthday, DOB Month and DOB Day.  Problem is sometimes (yes only sometimes) i get a duplicated DOB in my database.  These selects should give me a "July 23" as a DOB but in some instances I get "July 23 July 23".  Any idea how this could be happening?

```
<select name="dobmonth" class="form-control">
    <option value="">June 23</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="dobday" class="form-control">
    <option value="">June 23</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you php, javascript or VB to insert to your DB? We need that code to be able to help you out.

Comment: Show your full code - for client and server.